# Items alignment in the PopupMenuBarItem

Tags: dojo

I'm absolutely newbie in the Dojo, so my question may be too evident. Sorry.
I've programmatically created the complex menu, including MenuBar, based on the rows, selected from the DB.
All problems were solved besides one: the alignment of the final items and submenu items differ.[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8IRP.png) All submenus primarily were rendered in the same line. Only by adding the MenuSeparator I was able to divide them.
I'm lost I've found the example in the Internet, that shows exactly what I need (including the right-hand arrow for submenus) [Example](http://animeshsahay.blogspot.co.il/2014/03/dojo-menu-example.html) . I've used exactly the same algorithm to create menu. But I cannot get the same result.
Please, help.

---

I've noted that the image is not accessible.
In pure text it looks like:

```
                 Final 1
                 Final 2
                 Final 3
      DropDown 1
      DropDown 2
```

Indent depends on the submenu width.

---

Think, now I know what happened (don't know though, how to work around it).
The problem is the widget rendering.
The final menu option (leaf) is rendered as table row (**tr** and **td** tags).
The PopupMenuItem is rendered as div **between rows**.
Once more, I have no clue, how to avoid it.

---

Here is the code. A couple of notes:

```
    1.The rows is the two dimensional array
    2.The rows with ParentID=0 are the MenuBarItems
    3.pM is the MenuBar widget

    createMenu: function (rows, pM) {

    var me = this; // for references from the event handlers, where 'this' means event origin (instead of lang.hitch)
    // First define the indexes of the DB fields
    var xMenu_Id;
    var xMenu_Title;
    var xParent;
    var xURL;
    var xUser_Roles;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
        switch (rows[0][i]) {
            case 'Menu_Id':
                xMenu_Id = i;
                break;
            case 'Menu_Title':
                xMenu_Title = i;
                break;
            case 'Parent':
                xParent = i;
                break;
            case 'URL':
                xURL = i;
                break;
            case 'User_Roles':
                xUser_Roles = i;
                break;
        }
    }
    // Define the function to filter the menu rows
    // Parameters:  r - two-dimentional rows array
    //              p - criterion (the parent menu ID)
    //              idx - index of needed field
    //              f - returned filtered array (no need to use in calling statement)
    var filterArray = function (r, p, idx, f) {
        f = dojo.filter(r, function (item) {
            return item[idx] == p;
        });

        return f;
    }
    // Define the recurcive function to create the sub menu tree for Menu bar item
    // Parameters: parentMenu - the menu to add childs
    //             parentID   - the ID of parent menu to select direct children
    //             role       - current user role
    var subMenuFactory = function (parentMenu, parentID, role) {
        var i;
        var fa = filterArray(rows, parentID, xParent);
        var sub;

        for (i = 0; i < fa.length; i++) {
            if (fa[i][xUser_Roles].indexOf(role) >= 0 || fa[i][xUser_Roles] == 'all') {
                if (fa[i][xURL] != '0') { // leaf
                    url = fa[i][xURL];
                    parentMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
                        dir: 'ltr',
                        label: fa[i][xMenu_Title],
                        action: fa[i][xURL],
                        onClick: function () { me.menuAction(this.action); }
                    }));
                }
                else { // DropDown Node
                    sub = new DropDownMenu({ dir: 'ltr' });
                    subMenuFactory(sub, fa[i][xMenu_Id], role);
                    parentMenu.addChild(new MenuSeparator({}));
                    parentMenu.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
                        dir: 'ltr',
                        label: fa[i][xMenu_Title],
                        popup: sub
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Get array of Menu bar items

    var filtered = filterArray(rows, 0, xParent);
    var pSub;
    var user_Role = this.user.Role;
    for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
        if (filtered[i][xUser_Roles].indexOf(user_Role) >= 0 || filtered[i][xUser_Roles]=='all') {
            if (filtered[i][xURL] != '0') // leaf
            {
                pM.addChild(new MenuBarItem({
                    dir: 'ltr',
                    label: filtered[i][xMenu_Title],
                    action: filtered[i][xURL],
                    onClick: function () { me.menuAction(this.action); }
                }));
            }
            else { // DropDown Node
                pSub = new DropDownMenu({ dir: 'ltr' });
                subMenuFactory(pSub, filtered[i][xMenu_Id],user_Role);
                pM.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
                    dir: 'ltr',
                    label: filtered[i][xMenu_Title],
                    popup: pSub
                }));
            }
        }
    }


},
```

Comment: Can you share some code? If not, can you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) JSfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, just now noted you comment. Shortly I'll add code, although don't think, it will help - I did exactly what I've seen in examples. Thanks.

Comment: it actually works, i am sure there is something wrong with your setup. no need to change the tags since this will break a lot of things.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works excellent... But looks like ..mmm... downstairs. You know, DIV between TRs. And if there are several consecutive items with popup, they all are rendered in the single line. I had to insert the separator line between them in order to get a little more appropriate view. And what setup do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what's the problem. In the required array of define I erroneously import PopupMenu**bar**Item instead of PopupMenuItem. In the function the parameter is named right - PopupMenuItem, but evidently it couldn't help a lot...

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Regards,
Gena